# Jenkins - set env var to output of a command?

Tags: jenkins

I've inherited a Jenkins file and need to insert an environment variable. The variable is the output of the command:

```
openssl rand -base64 32
```

I've added it to the file like this:

```
sh('env.TF_VAR_sql_secret=$(openssl rand -base64 32)')
```

This outputs as I'd expect in the console:

```
env.SECRET=secretstuffhere
```

but running 'env' later on shows that this isn't actually set. So the command is working but I am messing up on the actual setting of the variable. I've also tried adding an 'environment' block as follows:

```
    environment {
        SECRET = """${sh(
            returnStdout: true,
            script: 'openssl rand -base64 32'
            )}""" 
    }
```

which returns an error:

```
env.SECRET=secretstuffhere: not found.
```

I really don't know what I'm doing with this but I feel I'm really close. It may have something to do with they way the jenkins file is structured?

Comment: The second approach should work. But you have to put it in the stage within a script block

Comment: I'll give that a try!

Answer (score 2):

The second block doesn't look correct. Like as you said, you were close to it.

```
    environment {
      SECRET = sh(script: 'openssl rand -base64 32', returnStdout: true) 
    }
```

Doing a `println SECRET` would give you the expected result as well
`W41NW9ly0kLsUgASJY7bpmSnqx5UYL6e2hefrMkrdIs=`.

[image: Pipeline-Snippet]

Comment: This works somehow, at least on windows: it will print the command and path where its executed, like in cmd...

Comment: from reference: returnStdout flag, you probably wish to prefix this with @, lest the command itself be included in the output.                                                    https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/